# LINQ grouping across unknown values? (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm using LINQ to EF in VB.net and trying to count the unknown values into groups by MM/YY.

DB Columns:

- Date
- Survey Response (String, Uknown value)

Expected Output:

- .MY = 01/23 .Response = "1" .Count = 3
- .MY = 01/23 .Response = "2" .Count = 6
- .MY = 02/23 .Response = "1" .Count = 9
- .MY = 02/23 .Response = "foo" .Count = 1

Edit:

- TID is just a simple filter to only return results from some category
- The .Response is a string value and for any month could have N number of responses (I’m not trying to group on known values)
- My LINQ is returning the count for the month when I expect, for each month, to get the count of distinct .Responses
- I *think* I need another select or I have the ordering mixed up, but I can’t work out the correct syntax.

Current LINQ Statement:

```
db.LR.AsNoTracking.Where(Function(p) p.TID = TID).
    GroupBy(Function(s) New With {
          Key .sr= s.SurveyResponse, 
          Key .date = (s.DateCreated.Month & "/" & s.DateCreated.Year)}).
    [Select](Function(x) New With {
          Key .count = x.Count(), 
          Key .response = x.Key.sr, 
          Key .MY = x.Key.date
     }).ToList()
```

Can someone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what is wrong with your code? What are "the unknown values"? What is `TID`?

Comment: I’ve edited to be clearer

Comment: I don't see an issue with your code; the query should be fine. I tested in LINQPad with anonymous type data and it worked correctly. What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 4.x / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x / 7.x / 8.x? What database provider?

Comment: LINQ to EF6.X, SQL DB provider. I'm going to recheck and make sure the input data is correct, i'm wondering if this was a case of garbage in garbage out